# mysql query takes over 300sec duration, over 20sec fetching, only 500k rows in schema

Tags: mysql

I spent a good while trying to figure out how to get this query to work. Now that I've got a working query, it takes far too long.

Could anyone please help me understand a better and/or faster way to achieve the same query results?

```
select 
  a.customer_id, 
  a.id aid, 
  p.id payid, 
  p.amount 
from 
  agreement a 
left join 
  payment p 
on 
  a.customer_id = p.customer_id 
where 
  p.customer_id is null 
  and a.campaign = "vsf" 
  and a.customer_id in 
    ( SELECT a1.customer_id 
    FROM agreement a1 
    GROUP BY a1.customer_id 
    HAVING COUNT(a1.id) >= 2 )
```

Comment: did you create index for `customer_id` and `campaign`? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: You have `SELECT` in `WHERE` for each row, then you have 500k * 500k operations (250 000 000 000)

Comment: Provide execution plan (EXPLAIN) for this query

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select  p.id payi and p.amount because with left join and where .. null you will get rows that exist in agreement and don't exist in payment
Can you try :

```
select * from (SELECT a1.customer_id , a1.id aid
    FROM agreement a1 
    where a.campaign = "vsf" 
    GROUP BY a1.customer_id 
    HAVING COUNT(a1.id) >= 2) as t
left join 
  payment p 
on 
  t.customer_id = p.customer_id 
where 
  p.customer_id is null
```

Comment: This reduced my query to 5.5sec duration, 0sec fetch! Thank you!

Comment: And If you add an index on a.campaign and another one on t.customer_id and p.customer_id as @Juan Carlos Oropeza said. it will be more fast

Comment: You're welcome @mrDave. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. [See also How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)